# Lining up elements (creating a 2x2 card grid)

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website (html), and am having some trouble making elements line up properly. Right now, my page looks like [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8FNo.png), but I want it to look like [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMAkw.png). 
Essentially, I want to create a 2 by 2 grid.
I don't know which part of the code is not permitting me from having 2 elements on one line.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```html
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">body {

  color: #404040;
  font-size: 14px;

  line-height: 22px;


  padding-top: 20px;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.card:hover {
  /*box-shadow: 0 5px 22px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25);*/
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
  margin-bottom: 54px;
}

.image {
  height: 200px;
  opacity: .7;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.image:hover,
.card:hover .image {
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.text p {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.fab {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -50px;
  right: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #0066A2;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
}

.fab:hover {
  background: #910500;
  cursor: pointer;
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
 transform: rotate(90deg);
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
<div class="card">
<div class="image"><img src="/sites/default/files/BannerTest.jpg" width="100%" /></div>

<div class="text">
<div class="fab">+</div>

<h3>Our Community</h3>

<p>Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
<div class="card">
<div class="image"><img src="/sites/default/files/BannerTest.jpg" width="100%" /></div>

<div class="text">
<div class="fab">+</div>

<h3>Our Community</h3>

<p>Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
<div class="card">
<div class="image"><img src="/sites/default/files/BannerTest.jpg" width="100%" /></div>

<div class="text">
<div class="fab">+</div>

<h3>Our Community</h3>

<p>Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
<div class="card">
<div class="image"><img src="/sites/default/files/BannerTest.jpg" width="100%" /></div>

<div class="text">
<div class="fab">+</div>

<h3>Our Community</h3>

<p>Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi pls insert html to help you

Comment: Add HTML code  block

Comment: @KhaledAlam I have pasted the code block above :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct code:

```
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
body {

    color: #404040;
    font-size: 14px;

    line-height: 22px;


    padding-top: 20px;
}

.card {
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    margin: 5px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.card:hover {
    /*box-shadow: 0 5px 22px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25);*/
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
    margin-bottom: 54px;
}

.image {
    height: 200px;
    opacity: .7;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.image:hover,
.card:hover .image {
    height: 200px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.text {
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.text p {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.fab {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -50px;
    right: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 48px;
    line-height: 48px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #0066A2;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
}

.fab:hover {
    background: #910500;
    cursor: pointer;
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.row {
    display: flex;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="image"><img src="/sites/default/files/BannerTest.jpg" width="100%" /></div>

            <div class="text">
                <div class="fab">+</div>

                <h3>Our Community</h3>

                <p>Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="image"><img src="/sites/default/files/BannerTest.jpg" width="100%" /></div>

            <div class="text">
                <div class="fab">+</div>

                <h3>Our Community</h3>

                <p>Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="image"><img src="/sites/default/files/BannerTest.jpg" width="100%" /></div>

            <div class="text">
                <div class="fab">+</div>

                <h3>Our Community</h3>

                <p>Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="image"><img src="/sites/default/files/BannerTest.jpg" width="100%" /></div>

            <div class="text">
                <div class="fab">+</div>

                <h3>Our Community</h3>

                <p>Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this 
wrap the elements in `div`  then  use `display:flex`

https://jsfiddle.net/rkv88/ug3qk1m5

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the example below, you can achieve your goal:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.cyan {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item red">item 1</div>
  <div class="item blue">item 2</div>
  <div class="item green">item 3</div>
  <div class="item cyan">item 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep 2 or more divs inline we can use different css properties like:
display: inlie-block, float: left, useing table, display: table and display:table-cell, flex box and so on. Here is a simple example below

```
body * {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* very usefull for responsive design */
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  float: left; /* not necessary all the times, depends*/
}
.card {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}
.card:nth-child(:nth-child(2n+1) {
  clear: left
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you.

```css
body {
  color: #404040;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 22px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.card:hover {
  /*box-shadow: 0 5px 22px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25);*/
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  margin-bottom: 54px;
}

.image {
  height: 200px;
  opacity: .7;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.image:hover,
.card:hover .image {
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.text p {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.fab {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -50px;
  right: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #0066A2;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
}

.fab:hover {
  background: #910500;
  cursor: pointer;
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/4.1.3/darkly/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md- col-lg-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="image"><img src="/sites/default/files/BannerTest.jpg" width="100%" /></div>

        <div class="text">
          <div class="fab">+</div>

          <h3>Our Community</h3>

          <p>Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="image"><img src="/sites/default/files/BannerTest.jpg" width="100%" /></div>

        <div class="text">
          <div class="fab">+</div>

          <h3>Our Community</h3>

          <p>Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```